# Storing photos from iPhone remotely and then deleting them off of device

Tags: iphone, photos

My dream scenario is where I can:

1. Take photos with my iPhone
2. Then press a button that uploads them to a server (ideally one which I own, but I would also subscribe to a service) and then deletes them off my iPhone.

The photos then should be easily accessible via a web client where I can decide which ones to keep, print or delete forever.

Any recommendations as to services which do this or come close?

Answer (score 3):

I usually use [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) for this purposes.

1. Take picture with iPhone.
2. Upload them to Dropbox via the Dropbox app.
3. Delete from iPhone.

You will be able to access those pictures via the Dropbox web interface. Or via their client on various platform.

Comment: He'll still have to individually delete photos from his phone…

Comment: If you do in once a week, you can actually do a mass upload of the photo that you have taken in the week, and then mass delete them all.

Answer (score 0):

I use [QuickShot](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/quickshot-with-dropbox/id405198996?mt=8) for this.  It uploads pictures that you take to Dropbox.  There is an option for "Save to Library", giving control over whether the pictures taken with this app are also stored in the camera roll.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not absolutely welded to having a web interface,
you can use Photos and Sharing.

You'd set up Sharing to send a feed to yourself. 
When you'd want to upload the photos, you'd select the photos on your phone and hit the sharing button and post it to your feed.

I believe, once it's been posted, you can delete it off the phone.
The feed is unaffected by deleting it off the phone.

On your computer, you can then Import the photos and delete any you don't want...Exporting photos will permanently keep the photos.